# X10 language deals with loose coupling or tight coupling?

Tags: distributed-computing, x10-language

Can anyone tell me if X10 lang (http://x10-lang.org/) works based on tight coupling or loose coupling systems?

Answer (score 1):

X10 supports concurrency within a single process (intra-place concurrency) and across processes (inter-place concurrency). X10 computations are intended to run within a data-center, not across the Internet. We use the phrase "(concurrent) clustered computing" to describe this focus.